# How to do this using Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following code in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/index.php [L]
```

What it does is, whenever `www.website.com` is loaded, it loads its content from the `/www/` directory and keeps the url parameter the same (Which is AWESOME).

Anyway, what I want now is, whenever any sub-domain (other than www) is loaded, I want to load its content from a `/subdomain/` directory and keep the url parameter the same (i.e. not display `subdomain` in the address bar/url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something that references part of the RewriteCond so you can use that as the sub domain folder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ %2/index.php [NC,QSA]
```

The %2 references the second token match (things in brackets are tokens) in the regular expression that is matched in the RewriteCond
[NC] means no case
[QSA] means query string append

Comment: But this displays the folder name in the url, and i dont want that.